# The Modify interaction doesn't work

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

The Modify interaction with `pointerMove` condition in the Select interaction gives TypeError: `this.a[d] is undefined (c)};l.update=function(b,c){var d=ma(c);Wd(this.a[d].slice(0,4),b)||(this.remove...`

ol.js str 342, col 728)

```
var point_source=new ol.source.Vector();
var PointVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: point_source
});
var layers = [PointVectorLayer];      

select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove    
});
selected_points=select_interaction.getFeatures();   
    var modify_interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selected_points
});

var view = new ol.View({
    zoom: 10,       
    center: [8530308.307502387,5342345.99739733]//Каскелен          
});
var map = new ol.Map({
   interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
   select_interaction,   
   modify_interaction
]),
   controls: [new ol.control.Zoom()],
   layers: layers,
   target: 'map',
   view: view            
});

map.on('click', function(evt){    
   var click_point = new ol.Feature({
   geometry:  new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate)});
   point_source.addFeature(click_point);        
});
```

Comment: Run your script with ol-debug.js to get a more verbose msg.

Comment: With ol-debug.js :
"AssertionError: Assertion failed: uid (59) of value ([object Object]) does not exist" Any ideas?

Comment: No error here with your script, perhaps you create a jsfiddle.

Comment: The error occurs when drag a point selected by hover - 
jsfiddle.net/qpkgvq3u/5

Comment: But is this what you want? Drag a point?

Comment: Add a point through addFeature method(not Draw), select this point by hover(not Click) and move it to a new location

Comment: If you want a full drag control I suggest you [this way](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/drag-features.html).

Comment: Thanx. The drag works perfectly. Could you hint me how to catch "moveend" in this code? It'll be what i need for full happiness!:)

Comment: I ask you to redo your question with your new code.

Comment: The new code http://jsfiddle.net/qpkgvq3u/6/ and my question is how to catch the moment when drag is finished?

Comment: So, is it done? If my answer is correct, mark it as correct.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on comments and modifications the answer to "How to catch the moment when drag is finished" is: you can do some action into this event:

```
app.Drag.prototype.handleUpEvent = function(evt) {

    console.info(evt);
    //some action

    this.coordinate_ = null;
    this.feature_ = null;
    return false;
};
```